# How to define expiration time on Cache in Angular $cacheFactory

Tags: angularjs, caching

I read about the Angular '$cacheFactory' but could not find any documentation on setting an expiration date for cached content.

What if I want to cache all GET requests for 30 seconds, how to I define this in the '$cacheFactory' or do I need to extend the functionality myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the problem too. The default $cacheFactory have no time to live (TTL).

You will need to implement this yourself. But before, you could give a look around, to see if someone already did it :

This one look pretty complete - http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/

If you really want to implement your own solution (by implementing your own $cacheFactory) and need some help, feel free to ask.

Hope it gave you some clue.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the cacheFactory uses localStorage or cookies to keep the data?

Comment: @AdrianE I knew that, but it's gone. All i know is that your should write your own cacheFactory that provide a factory from $cacheFactory (so that you keep the system intact) with in addition some functions/logic to implements the TTL.

Answer (score 13):

for TTL 1h, see below example

add factory:

```
.factory('cacheInterceptor', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
  var http_ttl_cache = {};
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      var N;
      if (config.timeToLive) {
        config.cache = true;
        N = config.timeToLive;
        delete config.timeToLive;
        if (new Date().getTime() - (http_ttl_cache[config.url] || 0) > N) {
          $cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(config.url);
          http_ttl_cache[config.url] = new Date().getTime();
        }
      }
      return config;
    }
  };
}])
```

then init in config  push your interceptor.
An interceptor is simply a regular service factory that is registered to that array.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('cacheInterceptor');
```

example of request

```
$http.get('/permissions.json', {timeToLive: Constant.timeToLive}).then(function(result){
```

Constant is:

```
.constant('Constant', {
  url: {
    logout: '/auth/logout'
  },
  timeToLive: 60*60*1000
})
```

Comment: This example doesn't handle `params` inside `option` object, but it can be simply fixed.

Comment: This is a clean and nice solution! thanks. I used $timeout instead of checking date to have a better tll vs plain cached semantics, but that's just my preference

Comment: @Yaron, could you please provide your timeout solution. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think @miukki answer's is great. Adding my modification to the request of @Vil

I modified the 'request' function of the 'cacheInterceptor' to use $timeout instead of relying on Date. It allows TTL to be more global for requests, So if one request sets a TTL and the 2nd doesn't but data is still in cached, it will still be used.

```
.factory('cacheInterceptor', ['$cacheFactory', '$timeout', function($cacheFactory, $timeout) {
  var ttlMap = {};
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if (config.ttl) {
        var ttl = config.ttl;
        delete config.ttl;
        config.cache = true;

        // If not in ttlMap then we set up a timer to delete, otherwise there's already a timer.
        if (!ttlMap[config.url]) {
          ttlMap[config.url] = true;
          $timeout(ttl)
          .then(function() {
            $cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(config.url);          
            delete ttlMap[config.url];
          });
        }
      }
      return config;
    }
  };
}])
```