# Angular $http call 'cache' attribute default values and behavior

Tags: angularjs, caching

I am making $http get call in my application. A single page has a need where this call is made thrice asynchronously. When I set cache to true for the http call it works fine ie it does make only one request to the server. Requirement is only to cache them for a shorter period. So I need to make for the entire page one request is hit to server and the subsequent ones are cached and also the next request to the page ie page refresh should make should hit server and cache the fresh response.

For that purpose, I would like to understand what is the default values like how long does the response remains in the $cacheFactory and is the cache type private or public.

I am aware of the alternative solution, what I am looking here is to know what is the time that this get call is cached for?

```
$http(
 {
 method: 'POST',
 url: '/test/api/component/getItem',
 data: {
   projectPath : projectPath
       }
  }
 ).then(unwrap);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define expiration time on Cache in Angular $cacheFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450738/how-to-define-expiration-time-on-cache-in-angular-cachefactory)

Comment: Any caching you see is done by the browser. The $http service does not cache by default and then only caches GET and jsonp requests. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service Reference - Caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching).