# Custom cache for HTTP requests

Tags: angularjs, http, caching

I want to cache the response [i.e. parsed JSON response] of HTTP requests rather than the response itself.  My data is big and gzipped so there is actually a fair performance hit decompressing this so would like to store the raw data itself.

Currently I am using a HTTP Interceptor for caching and TimeToLive mechanics [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080138/94278) alongside AngularJS' built in `$cacheFactory`.

So how can I, using an intercepter, stop the HTTP request and return my own response.  Note I still plan on using `$cacheFactory`, I'd just manage my own data.

```
.factory('cacheInterceptor', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if (config.cache) {
        // if we have stored this request, return it, else let the request happen naturally and cache after

        // Things I don't know:
        // How to return existing cache data and prevent the reqeust from happening
        // Cache the data I get back from a HTTP request
      }

      return config;
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: Any feedback Chris?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to inject this into your service and make your factory only handle the data received/cached. This time I only created a service for you which holds the logic of HTTP / Cache switch. I think you will be able to create a factory to handle your data/states on your own.

```
.service('getService', ['$cacheFactory', '$http', '$q', function($cacheFactory, $http, $q) {
    return {
        request: function() {
            function getData () {
                var deferred  = $q.defer();
                if (angular.isUndefined($cacheFactory.get('getServiceData'))) {
                    $http({
                        'method': 'GET',
                        'url': 'someUrl'
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        $cacheFactory.put('getServiceData', result.data);
                        deferred.resolve(result.data);
                    });
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve($cacheFactory.get('getServiceData'));
                }
            }

            return getData();
        },
        flush: function () {
            $cacheFactory.remove('getServiceData');
        },
        refresh: function () {
            this.flush();
            return this.refresh();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's enough to add `{cache: true}` to the request options.

see the [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)

```
$http.get('some/url', {cache: true})
.then( ({data}) => data)
```