# Caching in UI layer

Tags: angularjs, performance, user-interface, jquery-ui, caching

We've got a UI built using AngularJS (1.x) which interacts with a REST Service layer for all its data needs. The data in the UI is a simple object graph (JSON). The functionality in the UI is 99% display and just couple of cases where the UI allows user to update the data (which is saved to a DB by a backend REST service invoked by the Rest Service layer).
At present the UI layer makes call to REST layer which calls other back end REST services to get data (even if it already made such a call already).

1. Is this a case where we should cache the data in the UI layer?
2. Is the REST layer a better place to cache the data? why?
3. What are the points to consider in this scenario?
4. Are there any specific tool/library for caching in Angular 1.x apps?

The idea is to to reduce latency. Service layer hits incur a cost of seconds, this can be reduced to milliseconds if the ui avoids the backend calls.

Comment: what problem exactly are you trying to solve by adding caching ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$cacheFactory` thats built into Angular and a HTTP interceptor to give you simple caching which works pretty well for most scenarios without changing much of your controller / service code!

The answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080138/94278) has a great implementation that I have used before.

Note that this actually caches the HTTP response. Meaning any JSON in the response will have to be parsed every time you access it. However for 99% of cases this won't be a problem.